# What is the real weight of npm packages?

Tags: reactjs, performance, npm, webpack

I want to add an image carousel to a profile page, and allow the user to view the images in fullscreen mode thanks to a modal. It means - if I'm not mistaken - that the carousel will be imported twice: once in the profile component, and another one on top of it when the modal opens.

It is a heavy process, and I'm afraid of performance issues. I thought about creating my own carousel, but there are already many packages that perfectly deal with hand gestures on mobile, etc. However, their weight is sometimes dreadful.

For instance, the library react-awesome-slider - which seems perfect - weights 666kb! However, on Bundlephobia, it is supposed to only weight 36.2kb or 8.2kb gzipped. Who is right?

Will react-awesome-slider weight `2*666kb`, `2*36.2kb` or `2*8.2kb` in my final bundle? What is the maximum weight recommended to keep a high level of fluidity/performance?

Comment: No matter how many times, or where you import the library it will be included only once, so never 2x. About the bundled weights, I guess 36kb is the size of the minified library and 8.2kb is this minified version gzipped. So 8.2kb (plus headers and stuff) are downloaded through the wire if your server is using gzip to compress its responses.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like premature optimization. Don't care about your bundle size in this manner - if 3kb gzip is a lot or not. Simply, if you need that library use it. You will understand that having library for summarizing of two numbers might not be necessary before any bundle size issue will appear.

Bundle size that you always care about is the gzipped value, that's what client receives and has to "download" - that takes time. But as you can imagine, downloading 30kb on your computer at home is not an issue. On old device in middle of Blairwitch forest it might be.

Also, it gets send to client once per page/application so if your modal has it and your page has it it won't be included twice. Imagine having some library like Lodash, which is big and used (if I   exaggerate) in every function, do you think it be included 100 times?

Try to optimize the user experience in terms of ui/ux, that will be the first one user will quit your page for, not that he had to download 30kb of carousel, he will not even notice!